# How to properly cite a link to an image from a webpage

Tags: citations

Given that I am allowed to use an image for my paper due to the Terms of Use, how do I properly cite a link to an image from a webpage?

Do I name the direct link to the very image in my citation (e.g. [this](https://www.igorslab.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/MTL-01.png) link), or do I name the link to the website where the image is located, in this case [this second](https://www.igorslab.de/en/intel-meteor-lake-u-p-and-h-exclusive-block-diagram-of-mobile-14-generation-leak/) link.

In summary: Do I use/name the first or the second link for my proper citation?

The Terms of Use for the exemplary website I used in this example can be found [here](https://www.igorslab.de/en/about-us/).

Comment: Their [ridiculous terms of use](https://www.corsair.com/de/en/terms-of-use) probably forbids you to do that altogether. "Corsair hereby grants you permission to use the Website and its Content, provided that (i) your use is solely for your personal, noncommercial use; (ii) you do not modify or sell the Content; and (iii) you do not reproduce, display, publicly perform, distribute, or otherwise use the Content for any public or commercial purpose, including use of the Content on any other website." Yes, it _is_ ridiculous.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information! As this was only exemplary the questions still stands, which link (where the image is located or direct link to the image) should be used, if I were allowed (e.g. different website/manufacturer)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated my post and hope this clarifies my problem/question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the second. It is more meaningful to see the webpage where the image is from, rather than the direct link to the image.

You are not "citing a link to the image." You are citing the source of the image.

As well as the citation, you probably need a notice like "Image is copyright 2022 NAMEOFAUTHOR. Reproduced with permission."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your information about "citing a link" vs. "citing" a source was helpful for me as well, since English is not my native language.